# How to get range of documents

Tags: firebase, react-native, google-cloud-firestore

Let's say I've got 100 documents in my collection. My goal is to get the documents between 5 and 33.

I tried `startAt` and `endAt` but it didn't work:

```
  const db = firebase.firestore();

  await db
    .collection("pictures")
    .startAt(start)
    .endAt(end)
    .get()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you're trying to do isn't really possible.  Documents don't have a natural index or position within a collection.  To get ordering within a collection, you need to use at least one field on which you want to sort the documents.  Only then do they have an order, and only then can you page through them.

The [startAt](https://cloud.google.com/nodejs/docs/reference/firestore/0.19.x/Query#startAt) and [endAt](https://cloud.google.com/nodejs/docs/reference/firestore/0.19.x/Query#endAt) methods on the query require that you define some order.  You can see that in the example code provided in the API docs I linked to.  Note the following statement in the docs for startAt:

> Creates and returns a new Query that starts at the provided set of
>   field values **relative to the order of the query**. The order of the
>   provided values must match the order of the order by clauses of the
>   query.

Comment: While correct. Firebase collections are kept in insertion order if using push, and alphanumerically sorted in any case.

Comment: @PedroRodrigues There is no "push" operation in Firestore, but there is in Realtime Database.  The Realtime Database push operation generates unique IDs that are based on time, which means they do have an implicit ordering.  However, the Firestore add operation doesn't do this.  The generated IDs are **not** based on time, have high entropy, and no implicit ordering at all.  So what you're saying here isn't correct for Firestore.

Comment: fair enough, not very clear this is about firestore. You are still correct.

Comment: @PedroRodrigues The first line of code `firebase.firestore()` was my clue. Also we don't use the word "document" with respect to RTDB. It has "children" or "child nodes".  Firestore has collections and documents.